# Trying to build a docker-compose file from two docker run commands for two services that is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two images `mysqldb` and a `springboot-service` that are meant to be runned together. I have gotten the interaction between both to work when running the two CLI commands sequentially.

```
docker run --name mysqldb --network springboot-mysql-net --hostname mysqldb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_USER=a -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=a -e MYSQL_DATABASE=studentdb -p 3306:3306  -d mysql:latest 

docker run --network springboot-mysql-net --name springboot-container -p 8080:8080 -e dbname=mysqldb -d springboot-studentservice
```

I have created a `docker-compose` file with the following code, but when I run `docker-compose up`, the Springboot application is unable to connection to the db. The error it throws is

```
2023-03-07 09:52:49 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

**docker-compose**

```
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_USER: a
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: a
      MYSQL_DATABASE: studentdb
      hostname: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-net

  springboot-container:
    image: springboot-studentservice
    environment:
      dbname: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-net

networks:
  springboot-mysql-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Am slightly confused as in to why this happens! Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to remove mysqldb ports.

```
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_USER: a
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: a
      MYSQL_DATABASE: studentdb
      hostname: mysqldb
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-net

  springboot-container:
    image: springboot-studentservice
    environment:
      dbname: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-net

networks:
  springboot-mysql-net:
    driver: bridge
```

And do you create 'studentdb' database? If not you have to set a volum for mysqldb and create it.

Comment: I removed the mysqldb ports and added in an extra line into my Dockerfile (for the `springboot-studentservice` image) that was `ENV dbname=mysqldb` Doing both helped make my docker compose work.